# How to efficiently handle very high number of false positives in training data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am constructing a training dataset for a classification problem with three categories: A, B and C.  Once estimated/learned, I want to use the classifier to identify observations of types B and C in new data.

My problem is that almost 90% of observations are in A, so I get very few training examples of B and C and thus provide little information to the algorithm about how B differs from C.

Is there a recommended way for handling this? For example, can I throw out cases that are highly likley to be A before I construct the training dataset?

Comment: Try training multiple models on randomly selected subsets of those A's that are part of your training data, and averaging or combining the results of the multiple models.  Another thing : break it into two stages. Identify a class (not A), followed by a differentiation between B and C.

Comment: The two-stage approach you are suggesting is what I had in mind, too. Are you aware of any references on this or any documented applications?

Comment: I believe the technique is called "bagging." It's short for bootstrap aggregating. The second method is nothing special.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant the second suggestion, i.e. the idea that I should first identify "not A" observations and then classify further in a second stage..

Comment: The intention behind the second suggestion is that models like binary situations, and more so when the number in one class is closer to the other.

Answer (score -1):

This is an imbalanced class classification problem.

One common approach would be undersampling or oversampling - depending on the amount of training data available for you.

You can read more in [8 Tactics to Combat Imbalanced Classes in Your Machine Learning Dataset](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/)

Comment: Thanks. I think I was not clear. The problem is that I need to manually code the training data and it is not feasible for me to get a large enough number of observations in B and C within the training dataset unless I can somehow remove observations of A in a first step. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I still see this as an imbalanced class problem. Undersampling or oversampling is actually a method of "manually coding" the training data. If the data is too skewed maybe think of this as an anomaly detection problem (as the article suggests), identify B and C as outliers and then train a classifier to distinguish B and C. That is just a one of the many things you can try though.